# Compare dates ignoring milliseconds?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

**Is there a way to compare two calendar objects, but ignore milliseconds?**

I have written a test case that compared two calendar objects, but there is a problem. Although all of the day, month, minutes and hours match, the milliseconds doesn't matches. I get the expected date before getting the real date:

```
/**
 * @return
 */
private Calendar getExpectedOneMonthDateFromCurrentDate() {
    Calendar expectedOneMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
    expectedOneMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    return expectedOneMonth;
}

assertEquals(getExpectedOneMonthDateFromCurrentDate(),
             DateRange.LAST_ONE_MONTH.getToDate());
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the milliseconds to 0 while checking? You might also just get the long value of the date, round to 1000s and compare that. Btw, you might consider using Joda Time for an easier and more consistent time API (a similar API will be part of Java 8)

Comment: check this link, it might helpfull  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671001/compare-date-objects-with-different-levels-of-precision

Comment: i have used joda time before and believe you me i wish i could use it

Answer (score 19):

Remove milliseconds from your calendar

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: Thomas or Mishadoff solution has an issue. See my post down.

Comment: I think Author wanted to just ignore milliseconds. In that case our time is discrete by step equal to 1 sec.

Comment: thanks i will try this. i want to just compare, day, month, year , hour and possibly minutes

Answer (score 4):

You need to use

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

and possibly as well

```
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

if you just need the minutes to match.

Answer (score 3):

The solution of setting the milliseconds to 0 has an issue: if the dates are 12:14:29.999 and 12:14:30.003, you will set the dates to 12:14:29 and 12:14:30 respectively and will detect a difference where you don't want to.

I have thought about a Comparator:

```
private static class SecondsComparator implements Comparator<Calendar>
{
    public int compare(Calendar o1, Calendar o2)
    {
        final long difference = o1.getTimeInMillis() - o2.getTimeInMillis();
        if (difference > -1000 && difference < 1000)
            return 0;
        else
            return difference < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Utils.waitMilliseconds(100);
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    // will return 0 
    System.out.println(new SecondsComparator().compare(c1,c2));
}
```

However, it no a good solution neither, as this Comparator breaks the following rule:

*The implementer must ensure that x.compareTo(y)==0 implies that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z.*

What leads to `(x=y and y=z) => x=z`.

So I don't see any solution... But indeed, if you define some different dates, they *are* different, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the easiest way is to use truncate() from Apache Commons DateUtils ([Apache Commons DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#truncate%28java.util.Calendar,%20int%29)) to remove the milliseconds and compare the resulting dates.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Java 8, you can use the Java Time API, specifically [`Calendar::toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toInstant--), followed by [`Instant::truncatedTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-). Specify the granularity of truncation using [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

```
myCalendar.toInstant().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )  // Lop off any fractional second.
```

Example.

```
    Calendar oneMonthIsh = Calendar.getInstance();
    oneMonthIsh.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    oneMonthIsh.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

    assertNotEquals(oneMonthIsh.toInstant(), getExpectedOneMonthDateFromCurrentDate());
    assertEquals(oneMonthIsh.toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS),getExpectedOneMonthDateFromCurrentDate().toInstant()
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

Comment: Good answer, but it ignores the crucial issue of time zone in determining dates and count of whole days. But the Question is quite unclear, so not obvious what correct approach should be. If calendar-dates matter, convert `Calendar` objects (if actually `GregorianCalendar` objects underneath) to be `ZonedDateTime` objects.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call Calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0) to clear the milliseconds. Another is call getTimeInMillis() to get the time in milliseconds for both calendars. You could then divide these by 1000 before comparing to remove the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Joda Time if you are performing anything beside the basic date manipulations. In your case you can truncate the dates like so and then compare :

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().millisOfDay().roundFloorCopy();
```

Comment: This does not work, you need to replace `millisOfDay()` with `secondOfDay()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be millisOfSecond() instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
clearMilis(date1).compareTo(clearMilis(date2))


/**
 * @param date date
 *
 * @return truncated miliseconds
 */
@Nonnull
public static Date clearMillis(final @Nonnull Date date)
{
    DateTime result = new DateTime(date);

    return result.minusMillis(result.getMillisOfSecond()).toDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFromatDateTime(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    final GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime( date );
    //gc.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
    //gc.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
    //gc.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
    //block ignore millisecond 
    gc.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(gc.getTime());
    return strDate;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date now = new  Date();
    String currentDate = Testing.getFromatDateTime(now);
    String fullDate = "2015-12-07 14:53:39.30";
    String effDateStr = Testing.getFromatDateTime(sdfDate.parse(fullDate));

    System.out.println("Currennt Date: " + currentDate);
    System.out.println("Effective Date: " + effDateStr);
    System.out.println(currentDate.compareTo(effDateStr)==0);
}
```

Comment: little bit of explanation would be great

Comment: okay if we want to ignore milliseconds.we need to set milliseconds to 0 like this  gc.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 ) by using GregorianCalendar & Calendar in function getFromatDateTime. oh my code this using class  Testing

Answer (score 0):

If you use jodaTime, the setCopy("0") method returns a DateTime object with milliseconds set to 0 to make it easy to compare:

```
DateTime dateTimeZerodMillis = new DateTime().millisOfSecond ().setCopy("0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am way too late for the party, sharing my simple alternate approach for posterity

Two date objects comparision by ignoring the milliseconds using `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils`

```
Date date1 = new Date(1503055069000L);
Date date2 = new Date(1503055069683L);
//Here the two dates are differed by 683 milliseconds, if we want to skip just the 
//683 milliseconds difference then we can use the below logic
if(DateUtils.setMilliseconds(date1, 0).equals(DateUtils.setMilliseconds(date2, 0))){
    //your business process
  
}
```

**NOTE**: `DateUtils#setMilliseconds` method sets the milliseconds field to a date returning a **new object**. **The original Date is unchanged**. so until you are reassigning the object reference the original date object values are unchanged.