# Dozer String to Timestamp conversion

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I've setup my Dozer config to have the following default date-format:
    **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS**

When JUnit testing this however, I setup my object and then **setCreated_timeStampString("2013-05-12 19:05:32.887983");**

After calling the mapper to map from source to target object, I do my assert to assert the mapped value is same as source..

**However...** Junit spits out to me.. **org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<2013-05-12 19:0[5:32.034]546> but was:<2013-05-12 19:0[6:06.]546>**

Surely there must be some way to Assert this as being equal whilst dropping off the Nanoseconds part on the destination Timestamp object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671001/compare-date-objects-with-different-levels-of-precision