# Comparing dates with JUnit testing

Tags: java, date, junit, calendar

Hello I'm new to the site and have a issue with my application using JUnit testing. My issue is when I try to compare the Date method with itself it always fails. I printed the Date object in the test to see the problem and always end up with the package name and random letters. Here is the Date constructor:

```
public class Date
{
SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

public Date() 
{
    String today;
    Calendar present = Calendar.getInstance();

    day = present.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = present.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = present.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    present.setLenient(false);
    present.set(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0);

    today = dformat.format(present.getTime());
    System.out.println(today);
}
```

Here is my test:

```
@Test 
public void currentDay()
{
    Date current = new Date();
    System.out.println(current);
    assertEquals("today:", current, new Date());
}
```

Yet the result always fails and I get something on  the lines of:

```
comp.work.wk.Date@d3ade7
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First suggestion: don't give your own classes the same names as ones in `java.util`.

Comment: Next suggestion: if you're going to assert that two different objects are equal, you'll need to override `equals` (and `hashCode`, for sanity).

Comment: Next suggestion: if you want a decent string representation, override `toString`.

Comment: If you use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library instead of the troublesome `java.util.Date` & `java.util.Calendar` classes, then all three of Jon Skeet’s wise suggestions would be resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default equals object compares memory locations. If both objects are pointing to same memory location then only it will print equals which is not the case in your program. since they are pointing to two different memory locations it is always giving false which is expected.

If you feel your assertEquals(date1,date2) method should return true since the contents are equal then you should override the equals method. And when ever you override equals you should override hashcode() method also to ensure that you can confidently use your class instance as a key in any hashing based collection like HashMap or HashSet.

Here is a link explaining how to override equals() and hashcode() method

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html

And don't name your class same as any API class as Jon Skeet suggested.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you very much, read through it and implemented into my code and it works great!

Answer (score 14):

Overriding default equals method is not necessary. You simply use [Date.compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) to compare two date objects.

Answer (score 13):

Although the answer by @Shrikanth solves it, this issue also arises with normal Date objects. Two possible solutions are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671001/):

1. Make use of DateUtils.truncate (or even DateUtils.truncatedEquals) to compare the dates. This is something you could use in your equals method, or for normal Date objects directly in you assertEquals/assertTrue.

   ```
   assertEquals(DateUtils.truncate(date1,Calendar.SECOND), 
                DateUtils.truncate(date2,Calendar.SECOND));
   ```
2. Don't check whether the dates are the same, but whether they are close enough to eachother (for JUnit test sake):

   ```
   assertTrue("Dates aren't close enough to each other!", 
              Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) < 1000);
   ```

Comment: For solution 2.: I think it's helpful to wrap the `date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()` in `Math.abs()` before making the smaller-as-comparison. Then it'll work if either `date1` or `date2` is the older date.

Comment: Although you know the new Date() will always be later than the date created earlier, I do agree that it makes the comparison more robust, so I edited it.

Comment: I think it's better to use `.round` instead of `.truncate`, in cases where the two dates are off by a few milliseconds they can get truncated to different seconds. This results in a occasionally failing test.  With a rounding approach, this is not an issue. `assertEquals(DateUtils.round(date1,Calendar.SECOND), 
DateUtils.round(date2,Calendar.SECOND));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to override both equals() and toString(). If you override equals, always override hashcode() so that your maps work properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team recommending migration to the java.time classes.

---

This kind of work is much easier with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library instead of the notoriously troublesome Date/Calendar classes.

## Example Code in Joda-Time 2.3

Set up some data…

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime yesterday = now.minusDays( 1 );
DateTime nowAgain = new DateTime( now.toString() ); // New object, but same value inside.
```

Compare…

```
boolean isNowEqualToYesterday = now.equals( yesterday );
boolean isNowEqualToNowAgain = now.equals( nowAgain );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "yesterday: " + yesterday );
System.out.println( "nowAgain: " + nowAgain );

System.out.println( "isNowEqualToYesterday: " + isNowEqualToYesterday );
System.out.println( "isNowEqualToNowAgain: " + isNowEqualToNowAgain );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-02-06T01:31:43.157-08:00
yesterday: 2014-02-05T01:31:43.157-08:00
nowAgain: 2014-02-06T01:31:43.157-08:00
isNowEqualToYesterday: false
isNowEqualToNowAgain: true
```

## Convert

You can convert in and out of Joda-Time if need be.

```
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date ); // From Date to DateTime.
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();  // From DateTime to Date.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution to test date order

```
// date1 has to be before date2
if( !date1.before(date2) ) Assert.fail("Date1 is not before date2");

// date1 has to be before or equals to date2
if( date1.after() ) Asssert.fail("Date1 is after date2")
```

Comment: Confusingly the question was about the OP’s own `Date` class, not `java.util.Date`. OP’s own class does not have methods `before` and `after`.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time.LocalDate

For production code never create your own `Date` class (as an exercise it’s fine). Use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

For example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Africa/Niamey");
    LocalDate current = LocalDate.now(zone);
    System.out.println(current);
    System.out.println("Is equal? " + current.isEqual(LocalDate.now(zone)));
```

Output when I ran this code just now:

> ```
> 2021-04-07
> Is equal? true
> ```

If the code happens to run just over midnight so `now()` is called just before and just after the day changes, then you will get two different dates, and the second line will be `Is equal? false`.

Since it is never the same date in all time zones, specifying the desired time zone is crucial.

### If this was for an exercise

If you are doing an exercise requiring you to write your own date class, then it’s a fine exercise. In this case the answers stating that in your date class you should override `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()` are the correct ones.

In your own date class you should not base its functionality on `Calendar` nor `SimpleDateformat`. `Calendar` is poorly designed, `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome, and both are long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time.

### Tutorial link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.