# What is the right behavior of evaluatePreconditions on a date with milliseconds according to the specification?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy, quarkus

While migrating my JAX-RS application from Jersey to Quarkus/Resteasy, I came across a behavior change with the method [`evaluatePreconditions(Date lastModified)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Request.html#evaluatePreconditions-java.util.Date-). Indeed, in my use case, the last modified date contains milliseconds and unfortunately the date format of the headers `If-Modified-Since` and `Last-Modified` doesn't support milliseconds as we can see in the [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1).

Jersey trims the milliseconds from the provided date (as we can see [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2c5d5b6ed93240b5eb9a9592a46be66313a1006d/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.java#L747)) while in Resteasy, the date is not modified so it actually compares dates (the date from the header `If-Modified-Since` and the provided date) with different precisions (respectively seconds versus milliseconds) which ends up with a mismatch so an HTTP status code `200`.

**The code that illustrates the issue:**

```
@Path("/evaluatePreconditions")
public class EvaluatePreconditionsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response findData(@Context Request request) {
        final Data data = retrieveData();
        final Date lastModified = Timestamp.valueOf(data.getLastModified());
        final Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = 
            request.evaluatePreconditions(lastModified);
        if (responseBuilder == null) {
            // Last modified date didn't match, send new content
            return Response.ok(data.toString())
                .lastModified(lastModified)
                .build();
        }
        // Sending 304 not modified
        return responseBuilder.build();
    }

    private Data retrieveData() {
        // Let's assume that we call a service here that provides this value
        // The date time is expressed in GMT+2, please adjust it according 
        // to your timezone
        return new Data(
            LocalDateTime.of(2020, 10, 2, 10, 23, 16, 1_000_000), 
            "This is my content"
        );
    }

    public static class Data {
        private final LocalDateTime lastModified;
        private final String content;

        public Data(LocalDateTime lastModified, String content) {
            this.lastModified = lastModified;
            this.content = content;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getLastModified() {
            return lastModified;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

**The corresponding result with Jersey:**

```
curl -H "If-Modified-Since: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 08:23:16 GMT" \
     -I localhost:8080/evaluatePreconditions
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
...
```

**The corresponding result with Quarkus/Resteasy:**

```
curl -H "If-Modified-Since: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 08:23:16 GMT" \
     -I localhost:8080/evaluatePreconditions
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 08:23:16 GMT
...
```

This behavior has already been raised [in the Resteasy project](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-629), but for the team, trimming the date would add a new bug because if the data/resource is modified several times within the same second, we would get a `304` if we trim the date and `200` if we don't, which is a fair point. However, I maybe wrong but according to what I understand from the [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3), if several modifications can happen within the same second, we are supposed to rely on an *ETag* too which means that in the JAX-RS specification, we are supposed to use [`evaluatePreconditions(Date lastModified, EntityTag eTag)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Request.html#evaluatePreconditions-java.util.Date-javax.ws.rs.core.EntityTag-) instead.

So what is the correct behavior according to the JAX-RS specification regarding this particular case?

Comment: I don't understand the goal of your question: do you want to get a back up that Resteasy should cut off the milliseconds part? Because if you are searching for a solution, you gave the answer already in the question by pointing to RFC 7232, they explicitly mention to use the ETag "...where the one-second resolution of HTTP date values is not sufficient..."
Do you want to build a standards conforming service or do you want to have a cheap solution for an internal interface where you can influence both sides?

Comment: @cyberbrain I would like to know what is the correct behavior of `evaluatePreconditions(Date lastModified)` according to the spec: the behavior proposed by Jersey or the behavior proposed by Resteasy (and obviously Apache CXF https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/13e1dae57f5609259f935bfe5e280862e266dcb2/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/RequestImpl.java#L307)? Is it clear enough now?

Comment: Ok, I try to express your question differently - as I understood it: You want to know, if the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder.build()` method shall take the fractions of a second into account when it is comparing the request header _If-Modified-Since_ to the `Date` value of the `javax.ws.rs.core.Request.evaluatePreconditions(Date)`call - and no ETag was added to the `ResponseBuilder` between the `evaluatePreconditions` and the `build` call?

Comment: @cyberbrain No my concern is about `evaluatePreconditions(Date lastModified)` only, I want to know whether an implementation of  `evaluatePreconditions(Date lastModified)` is supposed to trim the milliseconds or not

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the problem correctly and therefore also the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `Request.evaluatePreconditions(Date lastModified)` at Resteasy 4.5 is wrong. The implementation at class [org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.RequestImpl](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/resteasy-core/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/specimpl/RequestImpl.java) relies on a helper class [DateUtil](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/resteasy-core/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/util/DateUtil.java) which expect the `Last-Modified` header to be in one of the formats: RFC 1123 `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"`, RFC 1036 `"EEEE, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss zzz"` or ANSI C `"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"`. Of these three formats, only ANSI C is listed at [RFC 7231 Section 7.1.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?rfc=7231#page-65) and it is obsolete. The preferred format for an HTTP 1.1. header is as specified in [RFC 5322 Section 3.3](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?rfc=5322#page-14) and this format does not contain milliseconds. The format that Resteasy implementation refers as RFC 1123 actually comes from [RFC 822 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5) but RFC 822 is for text  messages (mail) not for HTTP headers. Java supports milliseconds at `Date` but HTTP headers do not. Therefore, comparing dates with different precisions is a bug. The correct implementation is the one at Jersey [`ContainerRequest`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2c5d5b6ed93240b5eb9a9592a46be66313a1006d/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.java#L793) which before comparing rounds down the date to the nearest second.

[JAX-RS spec 1.1](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-1.1-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/) does not say anything specifically at this regard. Or, at least, I've not been able to find it. JAX-RS spec does not need to address this issue. The implementation must handle HTTP headers as per HTTP specs, which do not include milliseconds in header timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not specified, if the `evaluatePreconditions` methods should cut the fractions of a second or not. But: it is just "not fair" to compare two timestamps with different precision. You either should round the more precise one or truncate the precision to be the same. Especially since RFC 7232 even names the problem of the "low" precision of the HTTP header and suggests a solution (ETag).

I also found a SO question with solutions how to compare timestamps with different precisions: [Compare Date objects with different levels of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1671001)

Comment: Thx for the answer but I'm looking for an answer from a reputable source not opinion-based.